# Magento 2 change database collation

Tags: magento2, database, migration

> I am wondering if it is safe to change a magento database collation
>   from utf-8 general_ci to utf-8 unicode_ci.

I can do it from phpmyadmin or directly in mysql...
I just don't know if it is safe for magento. Will it work after or will create problems?

The reason I want to do this is that I am having some strange problems.

For example after migration from magento 1 I noticed that some attributes didn't appeared in layered navigation although they was filtered with results.

With further examination in database the attributes were fine and set in the products. But magento in frond end returned them empty so empty filter not appears in layered.

I am using two different store views. Two languages. So when I resaved a product in admin without changing anything then filters with attributes appeared in layered. This didn't happened with all filters. Just with those which didn't worked.

This happened with magento 2.3 version. Fixed with a script I made and resaved all products in all store views...This fixed the whole catalog filters.

But now when upgrade to 2.3.1 I lost in frontend from some products the custom options. All products in admin had custom option but in frontend didn't appeared.

When resaved the products everything came up again.

So I don't have a clue why this is happening and I thinking to change database collation.

Anybody has ideas please?